# Node dependencies won't install on Openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift

I've got a node project working locally but I can't get it to run when on Openshift.

I've found that when I SSH into my application and run `npm install` these are the errors I get:

```
npm WARN package.json video-looper@0.0.1 No README data
npm WARN prefer global dev@0.1.3 should be installed with -g
npm WARN unmet dependency /var/lib/openshift/538c552fe0b8cdca350001c0/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect requires depd@'0.3.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /var/lib/openshift/538c552fe0b8cdca350001c0/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect requires media-typer@'0.2.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /var/lib/openshift/538c552fe0b8cdca350001c0/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect requires parseurl@'1.0.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /var/lib/openshift/538c552fe0b8cdca350001c0/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/express/node_modules/send requires escape-html@'1.0.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /var/lib/openshift/538c552fe0b8cdca350001c0/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/compression requires on-headers@'0.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
```

and the list goes on... They seem do be my dependency's dependencies that aren't installing.

I can't work out why they install locally without a problem but not on Openshift. Has anyone encountered this before?

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.x",
    "mongojs" : "0.13.x",
    "hashids" : "0.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "0.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "0.7.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "0.4.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "0.4.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@bitbucket.org:pshelley/video-looper.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Video",
    "looper"
  ],
  "author": "Patrick Shelley",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Can you post your package.json file?  It also might be worth checking in your node_modules directory.  We do that with the ghost blog quickstart so that it will deploy quickly.

Comment: I'd check to make sure that your package.json file is formatted properly.  Also, you might want to check in your node_modules folder - futurealoof.com/posts/nodemodules-in-git.html

Comment: I've added my package.json file to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same issue and I fixed it with this

open terminal and run the following:

```
rhc ssh -a YOURAPPNAME
cd app-root/repo/
rm -rf node_modules/
npm i
```